# Signal Handling in Unix

Tags: c, unix, signals

I am learning Signal handling in Unix and having a hard time understanding what are `SIG_SETMASK` and `o_set` in `sigprocmask()`  and what do they do?

I understand that `set` contains the list of signals to be blocked or unblocked and `SIG_BLOCK` blocks the signals in the list and `SIG_UNBLOCK` unblocks them.

```
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&set,& o_set);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Linux manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) explains this well.

The previous value of the signal mask is stored in the last parameter (the old set) if that parameter is non-null.

`SIG_SETMASK` sets the current signal set. I'm not sure what more there is to say about that - `SIG_BLOCK` and `SIG_UNBLOCK` combine the current signal mask with the second parameter, `SIG_SETMASK` sets it regardless of the current value.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigprocmask.html) explains it like this:

> `SIG_BLOCK`
>   The resulting set shall be the union of the current set and the signal set pointed to by set.
>   `SIG_SETMASK`
>   The resulting set shall be the signal set pointed to by set.
>   `SIG_UNBLOCK`
>   The resulting set shall be the intersection of the current set and the complement of the signal set pointed to by set.

Comment: Mat kindly check my program about sig_setmask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184272/signals-handling-in-c