# Signals handling in C

Tags: c, unix, signals, interrupt-handling

I made the following program for learning the behavior of `SIG_SETMASK`.

The following program is supposed to block `SIGINT` the interrupt signal until the `func()` function calls

```
     sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&fOnemask,NULL);
```

where as fOnemask is empty cuz no signals were store in sigset before it. But as I call

```
     sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&fTwoCmask,NULL);
```

inside `func2()` function before returning,where fTwomask contains previous signal list made by `func()` function, the program starts receiving signals and the program is interrupted when SIGINT is passed.

Why is this happening?

```
void func();
void func2();

int main()
{
    int childpid,child;
    childpid=fork();

    if(childpid==0)
    {
        func();
    }

    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    return 0;
}

void func()
{
    sigset_t sigmask,fOnemask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask,SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&sigmask,&fOnemask);

    func2();

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&omask,NULL);
    printf("returning from func\n");

}

void func2()
{
    sigset_t sigmask,fTwomask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigfillset(&sigmask);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&sigmask,&fTwomask);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&fTwomask,NULL);
    printf("func2 ending\n");
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a problem with your sample: it never calls `func`. Please update the code (try and preserve the indentation) to something that reproduces your problem. (Replacing main with a call to `func`, without the fork, works as expected, sigint stays blocked.)

Comment: Mat when does sigprocmask() in func2() returns old signal list in fTwomask i-e; the list created by func().

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'll repeat what I said above: the code you posted never calls `func` or `func2`. Please post the exact code you're playing with.

Comment: I updated the question. It was removed while posting the code

Comment: Note that consecutive calls to `sigemptyset()` and `sigfillset()` as in `func2()` are redundant; in context, only call `sigfillset()`.

Comment: Why I run your code, there is no problem at all. The child ignores SIGINT until the last sigprocmask in func, as expected. Did you include all the relevant headers?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if I add a signal in `sigset_t` obj in main function and then call foo() from main. I then add a signal in another sigset_t obj local to foo() like `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&foomask,&oldmask)`. When I call `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldset,NULL)`, what will `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldset,NULL)` do?

Comment: @Mat in my case I send CTRL+C from terminal when func2() is printing on screen. Once it stops printing, func() doesn't print anything

Comment: @Mat yes I added all the headers including signal.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent process is interrupted by SIGINT because you never set any signal handling for SIGINT in the parent process, so it is set to SIG_DFL (probably, unless you've turned of interrupt handling in the shell, which is pretty unlikely), so the process terminates.

You're right; shells don't die when an interrupt is sent.  That's because shells take great care to ensure that they aren't killed by an interrupt.

---

One of the comments to the main question is:

> If I add a signal in `sigset_t` object in `main` function and then call `foo()` from `main`. I then add a signal in another `sigset_t` object local to `foo()` like `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &foomask, &oldmask)`. When I call `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL)`, what will `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL)` do?

Your comment (question) is confusing at best; comments are not the best way of editing the question.

As I understand it, you are asking about:

```
static void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    sigset_t mainmask;
    sigemptyset(&mainmask);
    sigaddset(&mainmask, SIGINT);

    // No call to sigprocmask() here...

    foo();
    return(0);
}

static void foo(void)
{
    sigset_t foomask;
    sigset_t oldmask;
    sigset_t oldset;     // Uninitialized
    sigemptyset(&foomask);
    sigaddset(&foomask, SIGQUIT);  // Different signal
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &foomask, &oldmask) != 0)
        ...process error...
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL) != 0)
        ...process error...
    ...other code, presumably...
}
```

This is what was written in the comment, as near as I can guess.  And because `oldset` was uninitialized, you suffer from GIGO (garbage in, garbage out); no-one can say what happens because the behaviour is undefined.

If you meant `oldmask` instead of `oldset` in the question, then `foo()` might look like:

```
static void foo(void)
{
    sigset_t foomask;
    sigset_t oldmask;
    sigemptyset(&foomask);
    sigaddset(&foomask, SIGQUIT);  // Different signal
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &foomask, &oldmask) != 0)
        ...process error...
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) != 0)
        ...process error...
    ...other code, presumably...
}
```

Then the second `sigprocmask()` undoes the changes made by the first call to `sigprocmask()`.  Remember, the SIG_SETMASK option means 'set the process signal mask to exactly the mask in the second argument' (unless the second argument is null, in which case, the third argument should not be null and it doesn't matter what's in the first argument since it becomes a call to find out the current mask without changing anything).

Comment: how can parent die when currently child process is running?

Comment: Easily...very easily.  Think of daemon processes; they're created by a forking a child and the parent dying (voluntarily rather than involuntarily).

Comment: if I add a signal in sigset_t obj in main function and then call foo() from main. I then add a signal in another sigset_t obj local to foo() like `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&foomask,&oldmask)`. When I call `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldset,NULL)`, what will `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&oldset,NULL)` do?

Comment: I am now blocking SIGINT in main also but still it is not working

Comment: Ok now it is clearing. One question when there is no third argument in sigprocmask and `how` is SIG_SETMASK, does it blocks the signals in the signal mask second argument.

Comment: If the third argument to [`sigprocmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigprocmask.html) is NULL, then you simply do not get told what the signal mask was before the new value was set.  So, yes, if `how` is SIG_SETMASK, then the new process mask is set to exactly the set of signals listed in the second (`set`) argument.

Comment: @Alfred "how can parent die when currently child process is running?" -- what would stop them?